# How can I put the return of a method into the GridView in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, sql, gridview

I have a `GridView` that gets it's data from the `SQL database`.
I would like to alter some of it using an external method, something like this:
`SQL in`:

- ID:0

Then, the altered method will be called with `0` as a parameter, and will return some string that will be shows in the `GridView`.

Thank you, Mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach a handler to the RowDataBound event.  You have full control to all of the cells in the GridViewRow, and can modify the text anyway you want.  Example from MSDN:

```
 void CustomersGridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {

    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
      // Display the company name in italics.
      e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "<i>" + e.Row.Cells[1].Text + "</i>";

    }

  }
```

Reference at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx